# Querying a view that is defined as "select * from"

Tags: sql-server, index, view

I am trying to understand how columns/indexes are used when querying a view that is defined as

```
select * from someTable where someColumn=someValue
```

Will using this view always be bad, or will SQL Server take into account the actual columns selected and use appropriate indexes in a query like

```
select column1, column2 from theView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would actually be a good exercise for you.  Create a table with a bunch of columns.  Create several different indexes (including a clustered index) on the table.  Try several variations of SELECT's against the table and tell SSMS to include the actual execution plan.  You will be able to see first-hand what indexes (if any) are used and what columns are returned.  Then, you won't have to take someone's word for it.

As far as SELECT * in general, there is some excellent information, courtesy of Dave Markle, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful).

To summarize the linked post:

> Here are really three major reasons why SELECT * can be problematic:

- Inefficiency in moving data to the consumer. When you SELECT *, you're often retrieving more columns from the database than your application really needs to function. This causes more data to move from the database server to the client, slowing access and increasing load on your machines, as well as taking more time to travel across the network. This is especially true when someone adds new columns to underlying tables that didn't exist and weren't needed when the original consumers coded their data access.
- Indexing issues. Consider a scenario where you want to tune a query to a high level of performance. If you were to use *, and it returned more columns than you actually needed, the server would often have to perform more expensive methods to retrieve your data than it otherwise might. For example, you wouldn't be able to create an index which simply covered the columns in your SELECT list, and even if you did (including all columns [shudder]), the next guy who came around and added a column to the underlying table would cause the optimizer to ignore your optimized covering index, and you'd likely find that the performance of your query would drop substantially for no readily apparent reason.
- Binding Problems. When you SELECT *, it's possible to retrieve two columns of the same name from two different tables. This can often crash your data consumer. Imagine a query that joins two tables, both of which contain a column called "ID". How would a consumer know which was which? SELECT * can also confuse views (at least in some versions SQL Server) when underlying table structures change -- the view is not rebuilt, and the data which comes back can be nonsense. And the worst part of it is that you can take care to name your columns whatever you want, but the next guy who comes along might have no way of knowing that he has to worry about adding a column which will collide with your already-developed names.

But it's not all bad for SELECT *. It is often used it liberally for these use cases:

- Ad-hoc queries. When trying to debug something, especially off a narrow table I might not be familiar with, SELECT * is often my best friend. It helps me just see what's going on without having to do a boatload of research as to what the underlying column names are. This gets to be a bigger "plus" the longer the column names get.
- When * means "a row". In the following use cases, SELECT * is just fine, and rumors that it's a performance killer are just urban legends which may have had some validity many years ago, but don't now:

Comment: Thanks for interesting information, especially also from Dave Markle. I tend to go by the urban myth that select * is bad. Allthough I absolutely see the power and usefullness of this with debugging especially.

Answer (score 1):

a quick example just to illustrate the well said answer by Scott Hodgin:

first you create, and populate a table

```
use tempdb
go

set nocount on

if exists (select * from sysobjects where name = 'the_table' AND [TYPE] = 'U')
begin
    drop table the_table
end 

create table the_table(
        i int not null identity(1,1),
        name varchar(108) not null,
        constraint pk_the_table primary key clustered (i),
        constraint u_name unique (name)
        )



insert into the_table (name)
      SELECT   'Rovigo' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Venezia' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Trento' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Roma' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Milano' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Lecco' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Como' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Bergamo' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Feltre' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Belluno' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Padova' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Verona' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Vicenza' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Napoli' UNION ALL SELECT 
               'Palermo'
print cast( @@ROWCOUNT as varchar) + ' - records were inserted into the table ' 

go
```

then you create the view with select * from

```
if exists (select * from sysobjects where name = 'italian_cities' AND [TYPE] = 'V')
begin
    drop view italian_cities
end 
go
create view italian_cities
as
select * from the_table
```

then when you run this simple select:

```
select [name] from italian_cities
order by [name] desc
```

you can see this result:

[image]

and here is the query plan (it follows the unique constraint, rather than reading all the columns through the clustered index)

[image]

and here is the [XML query plan](https://gist.github.com/jjradha/3edf619d01988ec530b64709b853167a)

don't forget to drop the table at the end of the exercise:

```
drop table the_table
```

Comment: Thanks Marcello, I actually did some of this already while waiting for answers, and in the process I also got myself a copy of the sql sentry plan explorer :) I ended up running the view and the table with different queries and examined the plans. They do infact act the same. Same index, same result (same reads and sizes of data), though the plan for executing towards the view triggered a missing index message. Quering the table directly did not show any missing index. There might be some good explanations for this, but my main question has been answered. Thanks